# jquery datepicker is not working well in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I m designing an application for mobile in which I m using jquery datepicker. I have date textbox and a submit button. The calendar opens on the submit button. But the problem is, when I click on any day of the month, this button gets focus and is clicked instead of chosing that day.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the button under the datepicker gets focused? I had that issue and solved it by adding a callback function to datepicker which would disable all other inputs when it got activated, then re-enable them again on datepicker close.

Check the documentation, datepicker has callbacks for both open and close.

Edit:

Instead of another reply, I'll post here.

When you init your datepicker, you can pass options, including callbacks. These are the two callbacks you want to use, what I've done here is grabbing all inputs in a variabel called "inputs" by $('#containingdiv').find('input'), then beforeShow I add attribute "disabled" to all the inputs, and on close I simply remove this attribute again.

```
date.datepicker({ 
    beforeShow: function() {
        inputs.attr("disabled","disabled");
    },
    onClose: function() {
        inputs.attr("disabled","");
    }
});
```

Comment: can u give me the link for documentation?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

You want the "beforeShow" and "onClose" methods.

Comment: can u give me some code how to use these functions? Although these callbacks will definitely solve my problem but I don't know how to use them

Comment: hey ninja, although the input text fields are disabled but not the buttons?